# gcloud compute API - where is the metric LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB_PER_VM_FAMILY?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, quota

I would like to exploit the metric 'LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB_PER_VM_FAMILY'

as recommand in gcp documentation : https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#disk_quota

I usually query GCP API like this :

```
gcloud compute regions describe [region]

gcloud compute project-info describe
```

there is well in the API response many metrics as 'LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB' (which become deprecated soon) but not metric 'LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB_PER_VM_FAMILY'

please note that console UI show well the desired metric ==>
[image: console UI show well desired metric]

so, which API call will bring me metric 'LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB_PER_VM_FAMILY'?

Is it a conf to activate on my account/cluster?

thx,

08/04 edit:
I'm able to run

```
gcloud alpha services quota list  --service=compute.googleapis.com  --consumer=projects/camembert --filter local_ssd_total_storage_per_vm_family
```

I see the limit in response, but no current usage ?

---

the goal is to use ONLY gcloud or golang api compute lib

Comment: Can you try this quota metric = `compute.googleapis.com/quota/local_ssd_total_storage_per_vm_family/usage` to view the quota usage and limits for local SSD in your project in API Explorer. Also could you please elaborate the question for better resolution.

Comment: I would like to precise I would only want to use API calls via gcloud or golang. ( the idea is to automatize it)

Comment: Try `gcloud compute project-info describe --project <your-project-id> --format='value(commonInstanceMetadata.tems[LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB_PER_VM_FAMILY])' `. Please note that this command assumes that you have set metadata with key LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB_PER_VM_FAMILY and its value represents the current usage of that metric

Comment: thx @Srividya but LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB_PER_VM_FAMILY is not in output for `gcloud compute project-info describe --project <your-project-id>`